# Can not send levels to switch pages

Tags: php, pagination

Am working on array pagination. I am having some trouble forming equations. what I want is when

```
$CurrentPage = 1 then $Start = 1, 
if $CurrentPage = 2 then $Start = 30, 
if $CurrentPage = 3 then $Start = 60, 
if $CurrentPage = 4 then$Start = 90
```

and so on..

How do I write the if else block ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 1 → 1, 2 → 31, 3 → 61 etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can also use this:

```
$Start = ($currentPage==1 ? 1 : ($currentPage-1)*30);
```

and forget all the if/else.

Comment: There is only one problem: What happens if `$currentPage` is not an int or smaller than 1?

Comment: clentfort, that's obviously a pre-condition for this code. *If* the value comes from a user, let's hope it's validated!

Answer (score 3):

If the current page is one, display from result one (for what ever reason not from result 0), if page bigger than one display from result (page - 1)*30

```
if ((int)$currentPage > 1) {
    $start = ($currentPage - 1)*30;
}
else {
    $start = 1;
}
```

or in a shorter way

```
$start = ($currentPage > 1) ? ((int)$currentPage - 1) * 30 : 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
$Start = max(1, ($currentPage-1) * 30);
```